# Understanding crash trace due to mutating a NSDictionary - is it due to Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am tying to understand the crash report with the following description:

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0x16d41730> was mutated while being enumerated.'

I understand the message - basically I was doing a loop on a dictionary or array while also modifying it ... and so am looking for the `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` was mutated while being enumerated, but only found the following backtrace on the interaction with Parse. I can't seem to tell what is causing it, and was wondering if you guys had any insights. Thanks!

```
Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2fd22ecb <redacted> + 130
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a4bdce7 _objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2fd229b9 -[NSException name] + 0
3   AppName                             0x00143b99 +[PFInternalUtils encodeObject:allowUnsaved:allowObjects:] + 1656
4   AppName                             0x0014523d -[PFJSONCacheItem initWithObject:] + 84
5   AppName                             0x00145371 +[PFJSONCacheItem cacheFromObject:] + 52
6   AppName                             0x0012049d -[PFObject checkForChangesToMutableContainer:forKey:] + 316
7   AppName                             0x001207bb -[PFObject checkForChangesToMutableContainers] + 502
8   AppName                             0x00122d6d -[PFObject mergeAfterSave:] + 240
9   AppName                             0x00123c37 -[PFObject handleSaveResult:error:] + 138
10  AppName                             0x00139123 -[PFUser handleSaveResult:error:] + 162
11  AppName                             0x00124573 ___31-[PFObject(Private) saveAsync:]_block_invoke426 + 258
12  AppName                             0x00185db1 ___23-[PFTask continueWith:]_block_invoke_2 + 92
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9a6d53 <redacted> + 10
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9ac689 <redacted> + 228
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9ac8dd <redacted> + 56
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3aad7c17 __pthread_wqthread + 298
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3aad7adc _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3aa721f0 ___pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3aa22ff9 _abort + 76
2   AppName                             0x001a65e7 _uncaught_exception_handler + 26
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2fd231cd <redacted> + 580
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a4bdf6b <redacted> + 174
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x39e881b3 <redacted> + 78
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x39e87d17 ___cxa_rethrow + 102
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a4bde2f _objc_exception_rethrow + 42
8   AppName                             0x001866c1 ___40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 376
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9a6d53 <redacted> + 10
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9a6d3f <redacted> + 22
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a9a96c3 __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2fced641 <redacted> + 8
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2fcebf0d <redacted> + 1308
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc56729 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc5650b _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16  GraphicsServices                    0x34bc56d3 _GSEventRunModal + 138
17  UIKit                               0x325b7871 _UIApplicationMain + 1136
18  AppName                             0x00110089 _main + 116
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a9bbab7 <redacted> + 2
```

**Edit 1:**

Per the helpful suggestions from the comments, it could be that I was modifying `PFUser` and trying to save PFUser at **two** places, once with `saveInBackground` and the other with `saveEventually`. To confirm, this what I have done.

**Action 1:**
In `viewWillAppear`, I call the following action on PFUser

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:now forKey:@"lastActive"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveEventually];
```

**Action 2:**
Also in `viewWillAppear`, I call this other action on PFUser - first, I find all the messages related to the user, and upon successful retrival, I perform the following:

```
NSNumber *totalChat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.activeChats.count];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:totalChat forKey:@"totalChatsCount"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

I guess now my more precise question is - could calling the two `save` functions on `PFUser` at a time span that is close to each other be the reason why its causing the crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AndreyChernukha. As I noted in the body of the post - I know what this issue means (like you described), but I can't tell where of the many places that I could done so that this caused it happen. I don't know whether the Parse functions was of any indication for this issue.

Comment: At a guess, you have called `saveInBackground` or similar and then modified the PFObject - In fact, it seems to be a PFUser.

Comment: can you post some code , where you got this crash?

Comment: Thanks guys - I got this report from Flurry so I can't tell which line is causing it. The `saveInBackground` @Paulw11 mentioned is very helpful - I'll look into this and post relevant code soon.